# TransactionScope and DependantTransaction

Tags: c#, multithreading, transactions, transactionscope

Can I get an example usage that is not related to either DB or File-IO?

I've read about IEnlistmentNotification and Transactions and was wondering if I can use Transactional behavior for my custom classes (like my own resource manager) which is in memory only?

Scenario I was wondering -
Let's say I have some data structure in memory which has some 5 properties (thread safe).
I launch 5 threads to update one property each (lets say its computationally intensive).
Now 4 may succeed and 5th may fail in which case I want to roll-back my data structure to its original state. Can I implement DependantTransaction for this case?

PS: I know I can manually save a cloned copy, revert it back in catch block, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There have been some 3rd-party implementations of transaction-scope providers for in-memory objects; however, generally speaking they're a bit flakey and not really worth the pain - *especially* since you are using threading. Frankly, I strongly suggest you look more at regular memento patterns, or immutable data structures that *don't need rolling back* (i.e. you just discard the separate, mutated copy).

Yes it can probably be done, but *unless* writing a transaction-scope provider is the **purpose** of your project, I would recommend you focus on delivering application logic first. Just sayin'

Comment: Thanks for the Memento Pattern :)

Comment: Can you give example usages pls.. I still don't know where it can be used other than DB..

Comment: @Makubex other usage other than DB? How about WCF? MSMQ? they both support transactions. However, **transactional memory** is ... awkward.

Answer (score 1):

Found these if any one else is interested -

[Another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517917/how-to-implement-a-memory-transaction-scope-in-c)

[STM in C#](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_transactional_memory#C.23)

[STM.NET Library](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stmteam/)